# Get data from a APIview in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my app I am trying to get the User data using a get request and it works in Postman but the problem occurs when I try to send the data from FrontEnd as we cannot send `Body` in `get` Request

URL:

```
           path('user/meta/', UserDetails.as_view()),
```

Views.py

```
class UserDetails(APIView):
    """Get basic details of user"""

    def get(self, request):

        username = request.data["username"]
        if User.objects.filter(username = username).exists():

            user = User.objects.get(username = username)
            print(user)

            return Response({
                'verified': user.verified,
            })
        else:
            return Response("User doesn't exists", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

How should I modify it such that I can get the data from `get` request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, your requesting URL will become

```
/user-info/?username=john
```

and then, use **`request.GET`**

```
 username = request.GET.get("username","default_value")
```

Comment: Even better, use `request.GET.get("username", "default_value")`, preventing any `KeyError`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Blusky

Answer (score 0):

The good practice is to use query params in such case,

so your url will look like,

**/user-info/?username=john**

and you modify your code to,

```
    username= self.request.query_params.get('username')
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic and the question is answered, but just to underline that the queried data, you obtained from the user in the API should go through the Serializers (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) to at least somehow protect against unwanted values. This will also avoid you directly querying the database models.