# React JS - Frontend & Django Backend with Azure MSAL authentication

Tags: reactjs, azure, django-rest-framework, azure-ad-msal

I have a React JS static web app that uses azure/msal-react to authenticate and a Django rest framework backend app that also uses Microsoft Authentication Library.

When I protect the views in Django with @ms_identity_web.login_required, I get the ff error in the frontend app: TypeError: F.map is not a function.

When I remove the @ms_identity_web.login_required everything is able to query just fine.

How do I resolve this error?

I have also tried linking the front end to the backend using the API link on the Azure portal and still was not successful

Answer (score 0):

The error message "TypeError: F.map is not a function" typically indicates a problem with how the `@ms_identity_web.login_required` decorator is being used in your Django views and typically indicates  how your frontend code is processing data,

If `@ms_identity_web.login_required` doesn't work as expected with your view, you can explore alternative methods for protecting views in Django, such as using Django's built-in `@login_required` decorator

Here is the way i am able to acheive using
`from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required`

**Create a Django Project**
**Step-1:**
Install the required packages, including `ms-identity-web`:

```
pip install ms-identity-web django
```

**Step-2:**
Store your Azure AD application settings:

```
MS_IDENTITY_WEB = {
    'CLIENT_ID': 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    'AUTHORITY': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/YOUR_TENANT_ID',
    'REDIRECT_URI': 'http://localhost:8000/auth-callback',
    'ENDPOINT': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me',
    'CLIENT_SECRET': 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
}
```

**Step-3:**
Create a protected view in your app's `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from ms_identity_web.decorators import login_required

@login_required('auth_settings')
def protected_view(request):
    # Your protected view logic here
    return render(request, 'protected.html')
```

**Step-4**
**Run the Development Server**

```
python manage.py runserver
```

**Create a new React App**
**Step-1:**
create a new React app using Create React App (CRA)

```
npx create-react-app azure-msal-auth-app
```

**Step 2: Install Dependencies**

```
 npm install @azure/msal-browser @azure/msal-react react-router-dom
```

**Step 3: Configure MSAL**
Create a configuration file (e.g., `authConfig.js`) to store your Azure AD application's configuration.

```
// authConfig.js

export const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/YOUR_TENANT_ID',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000', // Update with your redirect URI
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage', // or 'localStorage'
  },
};
```

**Step 4: Initialize MSAL Provider**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { MsalProvider } from '@azure/msal-react';
import { msalConfig } from './authConfig';
import App from './App';

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

ReactDOM.render(
  <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
    <App />
  </MsalProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Step 5: Create Auth Components**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';

function AuthButton() {
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();

  const login = async () => {
    await instance.loginPopup();
  };

  const logout = () => {
    instance.logoutPopup();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {accounts.length === 0 ? (
        <button onClick={login}>Login</button>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default AuthButton;
```

**Step 6: Use Authentication in Your App**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useIsAuthenticated } from '@azure/msal-react';
import AuthButton from './AuthButton';

function App() {
  const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>React Azure AD Auth App</h1>
      <AuthButton />
      {isAuthenticated ? <p>User is authenticated.</p> : <p>User is not authenticated.</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Start the Development Server**

```
npm start
```

**Result**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good day @SaiVamshiKrishna, thank you for the response.

I was able to log in but my only issue was the inability to query the data from the Djangorestframework application if the API view was protected.

Comment: this similar issue addressed  here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62065402/get-data-from-a-apiview-in-django-rest-framework)

please refer